# for loop for openpyxl multiple chart creation

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I'm trying to create a `for` loop to create multiple line charts in openpyxl, all at once. Certain indices in an array would be the bookends for the data the chart would draw data from. Is this possible in openpyxl?

My data in the excel spreadsheet looks like this:

```
1          Time        Battery Voltage
2 2019-06-05 00:00:00      45
3 2019-06-05 00:01:50      49
4 2019-06-05 00:02:30      51
5 2019-06-05 00:04:58      34
...
```

```
import os
import openpyxl
from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import LineChart, Reference, Series
from openpyxl.chart.axis import DateAxis
from datetime import date, datetime, timedelta, time

os.chdir('C:\\Users\user\test')
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook('log.xlsx')
sheet = wb['sheet2']
ws2 = wb['sheet2']

graphIntervals = [0,50,51,100,101,150] # filled with tuples of two integers, 
# representing the top-left and bottom right of the rectangular 
# selection of cells containing chart data I'm trying to graph

starts = graphIntervals[::2]
ends = graphIntervals[1::2]

for i in graphIntervals:
    c[i] = LineChart()
    c[i].title = "Chart Title"
    c[i].style = 12
    c[i].y_axis.crossAx = 500
    c[i].x_axis = DateAxis(crossAx=100)
    c[i].x_axis.number_format = 'd-HH-MM-SS'
    c[i].x_axis.majorTimeUnit = "days"

    c[i].y_axis.title = "Battery Voltage"
    c[i].x_axis.title = "Time"

    data = Reference(ws2, min_col=2, min_row=starts, max_col=2, max_row=ends)
    c[i].add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
    dates = Reference(ws2, min_col=1, min_row=starts, max_row=ends)
    c[i].set_categories(dates)


    s[i] = c[i].series[0]
    s[i].graphicalProperties.line.solidFill = "BE4B48"
    s[i].graphicalProperties.line.width = 25000 # width in EMUs.
    s[i].smooth = True # Make the line smooth
    ws2.add_chart(c[i], "C[i+15]") # +15 for spacing
    wb.save('log.xlsx')
```

Ideally I would end up making (however many values are in graphIntervals/2) charts.

I know I need to incorporate `zip()` in my `data` variable, otherwise it has no way to move on to the next set of values to create spreadsheets from. I think it would something like `zip(starts, ends)` but I'm not sure.

Is any of this possible through openpyxl? Although I haven't found any, does anyone have examples I could reference?

Comment: Create a function for making the chart and then you can easily call this in a loop.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I don't know why I didn't consider it before. Thank you for the advice!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Followed advice in the comments. Here's that function called in a for loop:

```
for i in range(0, len(graphIntervals), 2):
    min_row = graphIntervals[i] + 1
    max_row = graphIntervals[i+1] + 1

    # skip headers on first row
    if min_row == 1:
        min_row = 2

    dates = chart.Reference(ws2, min_col=1, min_row=min_row, max_row=max_row)
    vBat = chart.Reference(ws2, min_col=2, min_row=min_row, max_col=2, max_row=max_row)
    qBat = chart.Reference(ws2, min_col=3, min_row=min_row, max_col=3, max_row=max_row)
```